# delete modifier vs declaring function as private

Tags: c++, c++11, private, delete-operator

I read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770492/c-syntax-default-and-delete-modifiers) question, but it still doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It still sounds more like a sugarcoating feature.

What's the difference between:

```
class A 
{
// public/private ?
    A (const A&) = delete; 
};
```

and

```
class A 
{
private:
    A (const A&); // MISSING implementation
};
```

Same for `operator=` or other functions.

Comment: Making them `private` doesn't stop you (the class implementor) calling them accidentally.

Comment: @Simple - the executable will not be built if you try to call it..

Comment: I believe that's technically an ill-formed program with no diagnostic required. You will also get a linker error rather than a compiler error.

Comment: @Simple - yes, you'll get a linker problem, so it will be caught while building the project/program. It's safe, the function will NOT be actually called/executed.

Comment: @KirilKirov: it is not (necessarily) safe when building DLLs, because you have plenty of missing symbols in DLLs and only when you load them will you realize if one is (still) missing; and thus the error is caught **at runtime** in those cases.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - right, good point. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I would rather not expect this for Win32 DLLs, as opposed to Posix SOs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One difference is that `=delete` allows for **compile-time** errors while in some cases the declaration without a definition is only caught at **link-time** (at which the error message is typically not pointing you to the source of the problem). One such case is when you add a member function that tries to copy an instance of `A`. Even when it's not a member function of `A`, the error message about the copy-ctor being `private` is not as clear as using `=delete`.

To avoid confusion, I'd recommend you make the deleted function `public` as otherwise you will get additional and misleading error messages.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it clearly "highlights" compile/link time, **BUT** I'd like to add here, that without the `delete` modifier, the error can be caught event **AT RUNTIME** - see the comment below the question by @MatthieuM.

Comment: @KirilKirov You then might consider distinguishing between load-time and run-time. Most of the problems when using DLLs/shared libraries will arise at load-time, only if you manually and dynamically load DLLs/shared libraries in your code you will have a real run-time error. The rule when developing code is: Prefer compile-time over link-time over load-time over run-time errors. The `=delete` allows a certain class of problems to be promoted from the lower classes to the "best" class (compiler-time error) with improved diagnostics.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I meant exactly manually loading shared libraries, with `dlopen` for example.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that the purpose of the `=delete` code is explicit in it's purpose. Declaring functions as `private` / inaccessible was a trick. Although most people knew it, the error it generated was obscure (a linking/access level error instead of a semantical problem in the code - i.e. "you are using a deleted function").

Comment: In other words - sugarcoating? :)

Comment: :) In other words, they transformed an awkward workaround into a feature. I wouldn't call it sugarcoating.

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that the old-fashioned form gives undefined behaviour if the class (or a friend) tries to destroy itself. Within class members and friends, the destructor is accessible, so there is no compile-time error if it's used. Instead, you get a violation of the One Definition Rule. In practice, this will cause a link error, but formally the behaviour is undefined.

Deleting the constructor (or other function) causes a compile error if the function is needed in any circumstances; and states the intent more explicitly, allowing the compiler to give better diagnostic messages. This is especially useful when functions are *implicitly* deleted due to something else being deleted.

Comment: The OP means copy constructor not destructor

Comment: @ZijingWu: So he does. I'd just answered another question about destructors, and got the two muddled. It doesn't affect the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing which hasn't been mentioned yet: when inheriting / overriding, you can't `=delete` a function which already has a body but you can change a public function into a private one, making it basically inaccessible from outside.