# put disabled copy constructor in private

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

To disable copy constructor and assignment operator, it is clear that we could do either, since c++11:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
}
```

or for c++03:

```
class A {
 private:
  A(const A&);
  A& operator=(const A&);
}
```

however, what happens with this:

```
class A {
 private:
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
}
```

i guess this also leads to the same result. Is there any side effect?

Comment: Why don't you try it, and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ syntax: default and delete modifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16770492/636019) and/or [With explicitly deleted member functions in C++11, is it still worthwhile to inherit from a noncopyable base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9458741/636019)

Comment: I tried. all the three work the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter what access you give a deleted function - it simply doesn't exist(¹), so it is inaccessible whatever the caller.

The error messages may be slightly more confusing.  See for example [http:://cpp.sh/9hv7y](http://ccp.sh/9hv7y) where the first error is about "private" rather than "deleted".

---

¹ "it doesn't exist" is a simplification. It exists in the sense that it participates in overload resolution, but it is an error if it is the selected function.  Thus

```
struct only_double {
    only_double(intmax_t) = delete;
    only_double(double arg);
};
only_double zero(0); // Error - deleted constructor called
```

Comment: yeah, delete function actually does not exist, so accessor does not matter. this explains. Thanks!

Comment: I don't guess it's correct to say that _it doesn't exist_. Note that - _The one-definition rule applies to deleted definitions_. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.delete#4) for further details.

Comment: @skypjack: Yup.  It was true in the context of the question, but I've added a footnote (which ends up longer than the real answer!)